# How can I write a unit test to ensure a class definition is unmodified?

Tags: java, junit

We have a class that is serialized using java serialization.  This class should be very rarely modified.  I want to write a unit test that enforces this rule.  When this field is modified it means a lot of changes, and version bumps to dependent yet separate applications that call ours using java serialization of this object.

One thought is to just to use the automatically generated serialVersionUID.  The problem with this is that it can be modified based on JVM changes (which would be annoying to figure out).

Any other thoughts on how to approach this?

Thankfully, the class is very flat. Or, in other words, the class doesn't have complex sub classes. It is just a collection of simple java objects like strings, ints, and arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option is to fetch list of class interfaces, non-static and non-transient fields, constructors and methods using reflection API and assert they haven't changed.

This of course would mean that you'll have to do that for every class affected by this serialization (e.g. if your root class has collections of other objects).

For the reference, the SVUID algorithm can be found in the [Java serialization spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100):

> The `serialVersionUID` is computed using the signature of a stream of
>   bytes  that reflect the class definition. The National Institute of
>   Standards and  Technology (NIST) Secure Hash Algorithm (SHA-1) is used
>   to compute a  signature for the stream. The first two 32-bit
>   quantities are used to form a  64-bit hash. A
>   `java.lang.DataOutputStream` is used to convert primitive data  types to
>   a sequence of bytes. The values input to the stream are defined by 
>   the Java Virtual Machine (VM) specification for classes. The
>   sequence of items in the stream is as follows:
>
> 1. The class name written using UTF encoding.
> 2. The class modifiers written as a 32-bit integer.
> 3. The name of each interface sorted by name written using UTF encoding.
> 4. For each field of the class sorted by field name (except `private static`  and `private transient` fields):
>
>    1. The name of the field in UTF encoding.
>    2. The modifiers of the field written as a 32-bit integer.
>    3. The descriptor of the field in UTF encoding
> 5. If a class initializer exists, write out the following:
>
>    1. The name of the method, `<clinit>`, in UTF encoding.
>    2. The modifier of the method, `java.lang.reflect.Modifier.STATIC`,  written as a 32-bit integer.
>    3. The descriptor of the method, `()V`, in UTF encoding.
> 6. For each non-private constructor sorted by method name and signature:
>
>    1. The name of the method, `<init>`, in UTF encoding.
>    2. The modifiers of the method written as a 32-bit integer.
>    3. The descriptor of the method in UTF encoding.
> 7. For each non-private method sorted by method name and signature:
>
>    1. The name of the method in UTF encoding.
>    2. The modifiers of the method written as a 32-bit integer.
>    3. The descriptor of the method in UTF encoding.
> 8. The SHA-1 algorithm is executed on the stream of bytes produced by  `DataOutputStream` and produces five 32-bit values `sha[0..4]`.
> 9. The hash value is assembled from the first and second 32-bit values of  the SHA-1 message digest. If the result of the message
>      digest, the five  32-bit words `H0 H1 H2 H3 H4`, is in an array of five
>      `int` values named  sha, the hash value would be computed as follows:
>
>    `long hash = ((sha[0] >>> 24) & 0xFF) 
>      |  ((sha[0] >>> 16) & 0xFF) << 8
>      |  ((sha[0] >>> 8) & 0xFF) << 16
>      |  ((sha[0] >>> 0) & 0xFF) << 24 
>      |  ((sha[1] >>> 24) & 0xFF) << 32
>      |  ((sha[1] >>> 16) & 0xFF) << 40
>      |  ((sha[1] >>> 8) & 0xFF) << 48
>      |  ((sha[1] >>> 0) & 0xFF) << 56;`

Here is the code to recalculate SVUID using [SerialVersionUIDAdder](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/commons/SerialVersionUIDAdder.html) from the ASM 5.0 framework:

```
    SerialVersionUIDAdder svuidv = new SerialVersionUIDAdder(Opcodes.ASM5, null) {
        public FieldVisitor visitField(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, Object value) {
            if ("serialVersionUID".equals(name)) {
                return null;
            }
            return super.visitField(access, name, desc, signature, value);
        }

        protected void addSVUID(long svuid) {
            if(svuid!=expectedsvid) {
                throw new AssertionError("Serialization issue!");
            }
        }
    };

    InputStream is = AA.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + AA.class.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class");
    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is);
    cr.accept(svuidv, ClassReader.SKIP_CODE);
```

Comment: This is the best answer I could come up with as well.  I've abandoned the idea and I've fell back onto strongly worded comments. in the class.  Hopefully they don't get ignored.

Either way, thanks for the help.  I think this would be the best approach, it is just more work than I'm willing to dedicate to the problem.

Comment: I've added example of calculating serialVersionUID value for an existing class using ASM framework.